# How to return an enum element from a class method?

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I want to return an enum element from a class method to further use it in other classes methods or functions. How do i return the enum element or use it right to get the same result as using it in the non "classified" example below?

```
enum colors { RED, GREEN }

class testClass {
  colors _color;

  colors get color {
    return _color;
  }

  void setColor(colors color) {
    _color = color;
  }
}

main() {
  void test(colors color) {
    switch (color) {
      case colors.RED:
        {
          print('RED');
        }
        break;
      case colors.GREEN:
        {
          print('GREEN');
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  test(colors.RED);

  testClass abc;
  abc.setColor(colors.GREEN);

  test(abc.color);
}
```

When I execute that Codesnipped, my assumption was, that I get the output of RED and GREEN. Instead I get the following:

$ dart test.dart

RED

Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setColor' 
was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setColor(Instance of 
'colors')

Comment: Because your abc object is null? Try this:  testClass abc = testClass();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the value of abc is referenced to null. Since its not initialized.
You need to initialize the abc object, like so:

```
testClass abc = testClass();
```